# How to design database for blog system?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, rdbms

I am developing a simple blog application in which users can write posts and others can like, comment, share etc. i am facing difficulty in designing database.
What I have tried is:

```
user (user_id(pk), user_name)

post (post_id(pk), post_content, likes, user_id(fk))

comment(comment_id(pk), comment, post_id(fk))
```

PROBLEM: One user can have many posts and many users can like and comment on many posts. Whether I have to separate two tables like: `user`, `post` and `userpost`?

Can anyone tell me if anything wrong in this design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `comment` table is missing field which indicates user who added this comment.

And also it may be good idea to join `posts` and `comments` into one table - as comment is just a kind of post. So you will need just to store parent_id of post being commented in the record for comment.

And `likes` should be in another one table for many-to-many relationship of users and posts they like.

So your tables can look like:

```
users (user_id(pk), user_name)

posts (post_id(pk), parent_post_id(fk), date, post_content, user_id(fk))

likes (like_id(pk), post_id(fk), user_id(fk))
```

Comment: Hi..thanks..all I want is to count how many likes the post have from other users, and to know which users have liked the post (same as facebook)...Should I need another table.

Comment: It is not quite clear - what field `likes` in table `post` is in your implementation. If it just a number of likes - then you will not be able to determine - who exactly likes the post. In the implementation proposed by me "how many likes post has" is just something like (it's pseudocode) `select count(like_id) from likes where post_id = ...` and "who likes the post" is `select user_id from likes where post_id = ...`. Pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Like someone mentioned above. It would be better to have Ratings in another table

`Ratings (Ratings_id(pk), user_id(fk), Post_id)`

Something like the above.

Thanks